# Getting started with javascript, got a questions

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, getelementbyid, inserthtml

I'm following w3school beginner tutorial for JS. There's something I don't understand from code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var cars = ["Saab","Volvo","BMW"];
var text = "";
for(var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
text+=cars[i] + "<br>";
}


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain me the logic of `text+=cars[i]`? I understand that `+=` means increment, but I can´t understand the logic behind adding the array element to variable text.

Thank you so much for your quick replies! I've got a follow up question: is there an alternative to display the same type of information with having to use the

```html
var text = "";
```

and

```html
text+=cars[i]
```

pieces of code? If so, how would the snippet of code look like and what should I insert into HTML if not

```html
text
```

?

Thanks again!

Comment: += means not incrementing value ? it means concatenate to the existing variable .

Comment: `+=` doesn't only mean increment. When given string values instead of two numbers, `+` will instead concatenate. [MDN: Addition Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a+=b` is short for `a=a+b`. In your case you have `text = text + cars[i] + "<br>"`.

`text` is a string, and you are using `+` to append a value from the array (that contains strings), and then append `"<br>"`

Comment: thank you so much! I added a follow up question as an edit, but not sure this is visible to users that replied to my question, hence I'm following up with a comment to you, who answered first :)  is there an alternative to display the same type of information without having to use the var text = ""; ,  text+=cars[i] and insertHTML = text ? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The value of `text` at the end of the loop is going to be

```
Saab<br>Volvo<br>BMW<br>
```

where br stands for line break. So that each of them gets printed on new line.
And the last line of code

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

changes the value of html element which has id of `demo` to that of `text`.

Answer (score 0):

```
text += cars[i] + '<br>';
```

Concatenates element i of the cars array to the text, separated by a `<br>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Consider it like this,

```
text+=cars[i] + "<br>";
```

is actually

```
text=text+cars[i]+"<br>";
```

so that rather than deleting the old value it will concatenate the new word with existing string.(String Concatenation).

PS:As a fellow beginner a small piece of advice rather than following W3 Schools please go to site like [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com) which helps you to learn along with practice and proper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of `+=` as incrementing, that's `++`.

```
a = a + b
a += b;
```

Those two statements are the same. The bottom one takes the variable on the left side (`a`) and appends the right side to it (`b`), and then assigns it all back to he left side (`a`). So it's just a shorthand.

So what you're doing in your code is appending the string from `cars[i]` to your variable text.

This would do the same thing:

```
text = text + cars[i] + "<br>";
```

Once the loop runs, you will have the following in `text`:

```
Saab<br>Volvo<br>BMW
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript `+` is used for string concatenation

The code

```
for(var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
   text+=cars[i] + "<br>";
}
```

is picking each element from the array and concatenating "
" to it.

If you console log the text before setting the innerHTML, it looks something like this -

```
"Saab<br>Volvo<br>BMW<br>"
```

Answer (score 0):

here they do it actually just to show theres no point of doing it this way they just wanna show to reach each individual inside an array and concatanate it into a string the very same thing you can do with Array.prototype.join() method dont think here that u must use as they show always concatanate into a string if you want you can simply use every single individual inside as u wish as well

Answer (score 0):

+= is not increment. It's adding (in this case concatenation) and saving result in the same variable.

```
var a +=b;
```

Is the same to:

```
var = a + b;
```

In your case script concatenates all array elements into one string and adding `<br>` tags between them.